# Without graphing, determine if a critical-point value of a function is a local or global extrema

Tags: calculus

> Question: Without looking at the graph, how would I know if the value
>   at a critical point of a function is a local extrema or a global
>   extrema?

To give details as to what kind of confusion I am having, consider the function $$f(x)=x^{2/3}(x^2 - 4).$$

We find that $$f'(x)=\frac{8x^2-8}{3\sqrt[3]{x}},$$
so that the critical points are $-1, 0, 1$. Then we have that $f(\pm1) = -3$ and $f(0)=0$. Here $-3$ is the global min value of the function, but $0$ is the local min value of the function. I was able to tell all of this by looking at the graph, so my question becomes: can I tell the difference b/w local and global max/min values without plotting the function?

Comment: For a lot of worked examples using the first derivative test, see my [29 October 2006 sci.math post *Sign charts and the first derivative test*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sci.math/Sign$20charts$20and$20the$20first$20derivative$20test%7Csort:date/sci.math/TpC_fn-MkU4/QW0IXAWhqf4J). To see the sign charts properly, you'll have to copy the post somewhere that you to use fixed width font. Google used to use this for sci.math (and all USENET groups used to at one time), but someone who didn't know better retroactively changed everything in google's archive to a variable font width.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, thanks so much. I'll go through the problems in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about a real function $f(x) = y$  all extremes of the function are either critical points, boundary points or points which diverge to infinity, so all you need to do is to look at the value of the function at these points to determine the maximum and the minimum of the function. Here you need to consider $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)  $$ as well. i think that's what confused you here, always consider the boundaries of the function you're looking at, which in the case of this function is $\pm\infty$ as it is defined for all real numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't checking the limits at $\pm \infty$. That does see to help in determining if we have a local or global extrema.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if a critical point is an extreme point, check the sign of the first derivative near that point -- that is, find out the value of the first derivative at points close to the point in question on either side.

What do you check for -- a change of sign, either from $+$ to $-$ or vice versa. This is necessary and sufficient to show that the point in question is an extreme point. This means that if the first derivative maintains its sign close to where it vanishes, then you do not have an extreme point there.

Here you have that $$f'(x)=\frac83x^{5/3}-\frac83x^{-1/3}=\frac83x^{-1/3}\left(x^2-1\right),$$ so that your critical points are $x=\pm 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is to determine without graphing or derivatives. Note that

$$f(x)=x^{2/3}(x^2 - 4)=(x^{2/3}-1)^4+2(2x^{2/3}+1)(x^{2/3}-1)^2-3\ge -3$$

where the equality is at $x=\pm1$.

Thus, $-3$ is the global minimum and $0$, if defined, is local due to $0<f(3)$.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why gives $x=0$ a critical point? $$f'(0)=\frac{-8}{3\sqrt[3]{0}}$$ is not defined.(If your derivative is right)
Then use the second derivative test.

Comment: This question comes in Thomas' Calculus before the second derivative test is introduced, and also in the book the author says where the derivative becomes undefined is also to be considered a critical point.

Comment: The second derivative test usually doesn't help much with determining global extrema.